# Why does X run behind a full screen video, but stops when the video stops?

Tags: video, hdmi

I'm playing around with a Raspberry Pi. It uses a little GPU to play full screen videos.

1. I open an SSH terminal, and run a clip with Omxplayer. It runs flawlessly in full screen through HDMI.
2. If I then launch X (startx) from a remote terminal, and open a webpage in a browser, I can't see it because the video is in front of it.
3. If I then pkill the video, I see the web page that was hiding behind it all this time. So far so good.
4. I redo 1, launching Omxplayer. Doesn't work. I just see the terminal and information about the video running, but there is no actual video being sent through HDMI.

How come?